# AWS DMS SQL Server to Dynamo DB Columns with Empty data dropped

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to migrate from SQL Server to DynamoDB. The issue is that when there is a column in my SQL server View that doesn’t have a value to it (ie a blank or null varchar) it removes it from the DyanmoDB row completely, it doesn’t exists rather then the attribute existing and having a blank value to it.

How do you keep blank or null columns in from the source SQL server database? I see DMS has DynamoDb expressions you could possibly use, or maybe a transform rule?

Has anybody come across this before?

Comment: Is it `null` or is it an empty string? Most JSON serializers won't serialize null properties by default (i.e.: they're entirely skipped in the JSON output), but should output empty strings. Historically AWS's DynamoDB implementation has even had issues deserializing data containing properties with `null` values. [Migrating from a relational database to a DynamoDB table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html#CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.RDBMS2DynamoDB) specifically says: _Note: NULL data from the source are ignored on the target._

Comment: Good catch on the documentation, ok so null values will end up getting ignored for migration. In my case these values are varchar but empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like based on this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html#CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.RDBMS2DynamoDB

NULL data from the source are ignored on the target.

This was my issue, I simply changed it from `NULL` to `"NULL"` for migration.

Answer (score 1):

[DMS drops null values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.DynamoDB.html)

> NULL data from the source are ignored on the target.

Furthermore, you mention your particular use-case uses empty strings. DMS uses DynamoDB Mapper Client under the hood which [does not support empty strings](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html), so those are also dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I figured as much but couldn’t find the documentation to support. My question is more so asking if there is a work around for it vos DMS transformation rules :)